# why implementation project(':ToastLibrary') can not be written implementation(project ':ToastLibrary')?

Tags: groovy, android-gradle-plugin

In Groovy , We can Omit brackets. like

```
def add(a, b) {
    a + b
}
println add(1,2)  
println add 1, 2 //same result
```

so ,we can change `implementation(project(':ToastLibrary'))` to `implementation project(':ToastLibrary')`, then I think code below is right

```
implementation project ':ToastLibrary'
implementation(project ':ToastLibrary')
```

but error.

```
Could not get unknown property ':ToastLibrary' for DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':app'', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.
```

please tell me why!

Answer (score 1):

Your "prove" is flawed.  You get also an error when `add` accepts only
one argument:

```
def add(a) {
    a + 1
}
println add 1
```

Gives:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: add for class: x
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: add for class: x        
        at x.run(x.groovy:5)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Without the `,` to mark the actual arguments, the parser will read this
basically as:

```
println(add).1
```

(as if you would like to chain the calls)